# Custom layout for search result

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress 3.5.1 I want to create & use custom layout to display search result. I googled and found http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page but this is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved my problem and now very happy :)

I write following script in `search.php` file

```
while ( have_posts() ) {

                the_post();

                //get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
                $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
                $feed = truncate( strip_tags( get_the_content($post->ID) ), 0, 300, "[...]");

                echo '<div class="posts">';
                echo '<div style="float:left">';
                echo '<a class="featured-img">
                        '.the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail').'
                    </a>';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<div class="posts-content">';
                echo    '<div class="heading"><a href="'.$permalink.'">'.$title.'</a></div>';
                echo    '<div class="comments">&nbsp;</div>'.
                        $feed
                        .'</div>';

                echo '</div>';
            }
```